# PHP - populate a select drop down from MySQL DB and have that field auto-populated in a form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to accomplish two things with the code below. Firstly I want my select options to be populated form my database. Secondly I want the field in the form to have the stored value selected on page load (like in a profile for a member). The way I have implemented below works, kind of, but I have two problems. Firstly if you open the dropdown then the selected option appears twice (once at the top and once in its normal position). Secondly if it is a required field then the user has to open the dropdown and select it again, even though it is appearing in the field (horrible ux). If it is not a required field the form acts as if nothing is selected and I get a Undefined index error further down the line. I am very sure there is a better way to implement what I am trying to achieve that wont give me these problems... all help greatly appriciated.

```
<?php

$query6 = "SELECT catname FROM travisor_catagory";
$result6 = mysqli_query($conn, $query6) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$queryread3 = "SELECT * FROM travisor_catagory WHERE id = $catagory";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $queryread3) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {

        $cat = $row["catname"];

    }
}

echo   "<div class='form-group'>
        <label>Catagory *</label>
        <select class='form-control' name='catagory' required>
        <option disabled selected value> $cat </option>";

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result6) > 0) {
                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6)) {
                    $catagory2 = $row2["catname"];
                    echo "<option>$catagory2</option>"; 
                }
            }

echo    "</select>"

?>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql1` instead of the visually similar `$sqll`.

Comment: Put in a condition `if($cat !== $category2){/* only create option now */}`. By the way, no need for a while loop if you know you're getting only one result from that first query.

Comment: @PHPglue can you expand a little please. Where should I put the condition? Thanks I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix things up so much.....

When you get into larger programs, you will get lost really quickly, so K.I.S.S.!!!

You can 'jump' in/out of HTML and back to PHP to echo the $options variable, then back to HTML to complete the select.  (this is my description of it when I teach newbies - this concept of 'jump in/out' works for PHP, HTML, JS - well any languages that you can combine in one page... - it is worth grasping the concept!)

First, get the options you will need with ONE query (watch how we take care of the selected one as well) - this will make a 'packet' of data in the $options variable.

```
<?php
    // declare some values that we'll use later
    $options = '';
    // gather the data for the options
    $sql = "SELECT id, catname FROM travisor_catagory";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $selected = '';
            if($category == $row['id']){
                $selected = "selected";
            }
            $options .=  '<option ' . $selected . ' value="' . $row["id"] . '">" . $row["catname"] . "</option>"; 
        }
    }
// now we will 'jump' out of PHP and back to HTML
?>
<!-- we are in HTML, so comments and language changed... -->
<div class='form-group'>
    <label>Catagory *</label>
    <select class='form-control' name='catagory' required>
        <!-- here we 'jump' out of HTML and into PHP to use the $options variable -->
        <?php echo $options; // and back out of PHP to HTML... ?>
        <!-- where we finish up our select and whatever other HTML things -->
    </select>
</div>
```

That should take care of both your issues with what you had.....

BTW, it looks like you are using Bootstrap - if so, I HIGHLY recommend you check this out (changed my life about fighting with select boxes! :) [Bootstrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)